# Post a tweet on cron run

Tags: social-network

I've got a piece of code below that takes a line from a book I wrote, hashtags some of the main words and posts it to twitter. I want it to automatically run on cron. However, usually the user is sent to twitter to authenticate and then redirected to the application. I'm not sure how to handle it. Apologies but any advice would be great.  I'm thinking that I can use the Twitter module if it has an api?

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
include('eden.php');
eden()->setLoader();
//The client requests the server for a consumer key and a consumer secret out of band.
$auth = eden('twitter')->auth('***', '***');
//The client uses the consumer key to obtain a request token and a secret.



if(!isset($_SESSION['access_token'], $_SESSION['access_secret'])) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['request_secret'])) {
        $token                      = $auth->getRequestToken();
        $_SESSION['request_secret'] = $token['oauth_token_secret'];
        $login                      = $auth->getLoginUrl($token['oauth_token'], 'http://localhost/weavetweet/');
        header('Location:' . $login);
        exit;
    }


   if (isset($_GET['oauth_token'], $_GET['oauth_verifier'])) {
        $token                      = $auth->getAccessToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['request_secret'], $_GET['oauth_verifier']);
        $_SESSION['access_token']   = $token['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_token']    = $token['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_verifier'] = $token['oauth_verifier'];
        $_SESSION['access_secret']  = $token['oauth_token_secret'];
        unset($_SESSION['request_secret']);
    }
}
//print_r($_SESSION);
//load in the book
$txt_file  = file_get_contents('***.txt');
//Explode into sentences
$sentences = explode('.', $txt_file);
shuffle($sentences);
//shorten to 100 chars
$tweet     = substr(array_pop($sentences), 0, 88);
$tweet = explode(' ', $tweet);
array_pop($tweet);
$tweet = implode(' ', $tweet);
$length_of_tweet = strlen($tweet);

$commonWords = array('A', 'He', 'me', 'however', 'the','I', 'i', 'a','able','about','above','abroad','according','accordingly','across','actually','adj','after','afterwards','again','against','ago','ahead','ain\'t','all','allow','allows','almost','alone','along','alongside','already','also','although','always','am','amid','amidst','among','amongst','an','and','another','any','anybody','anyhow','anyone','anything','anyway','anyways','anywhere','apart','appear','appreciate','appropriate','are','aren\'t','around','as','a\'s','aside','ask','asking','associated','at','available','away','awfully','b','back','backward','backwards','be','became','because','become','becomes','becoming','been','before','beforehand','begin','behind','being','believe','below','beside','besides','best','better','between','beyond','both','brief','but','by','c','came','can','cannot','cant','can\'t','caption','cause','causes','certain','certainly','changes','clearly','c\'mon','co','co.','com','come','comes','concerning','consequently','consider','considering','contain','containing','contains','corresponding','could','couldn\'t','course','c\'s','currently','d','dare','daren\'t','definitely','described','despite','did','didn\'t','different','directly','do','does','doesn\'t','doing','done','don\'t','down','downwards','during','e','each','edu','eg','eight','eighty','either','else','elsewhere','end','ending','enough','entirely','especially','et','etc','even','ever','evermore','every','everybody','everyone','everything','everywhere','ex','exactly','example','except','f','fairly','far','farther','few','fewer','fifth','first','five','followed','following','follows','for','forever','former','formerly','forth','forward','found','four','from','further','furthermore','g','get','gets','getting','given','gives','go','goes','going','gone','got','gotten','greetings','h','had','hadn\'t','half','happens','hardly','has','hasn\'t','have','haven\'t','having','he','he\'d','he\'ll','hello','help','hence','her','here','hereafter','hereby','herein','here\'s','hereupon','hers','herself','he\'s','hi','him','himself','his','hither','hopefully','how','howbeit','however','hundred','i','i\'d','ie','if','ignored','i\'ll','i\'m','immediate','in','inasmuch','inc','inc.','indeed','indicate','indicated','indicates','inner','inside','insofar','instead','into','inward','is','isn\'t','it','it\'d','it\'ll','its','it\'s','itself','i\'ve','j','just','k','keep','keeps','kept','know','known','knows','l','last','lately','later','latter','latterly','least','less','lest','let','let\'s','like','liked','likely','likewise','little','look','looking','looks','low','lower','ltd','m','made','mainly','make','makes','many','may','maybe','mayn\'t','me','mean','meantime','meanwhile','merely','might','mightn\'t','mine','minus','miss','more','moreover','most','mostly','mr','mrs','much','must','mustn\'t','my','myself','n','name','namely','nd','near','nearly','necessary','need','needn\'t','needs','neither','never','neverf','neverless','nevertheless','new','next','nine','ninety','no','nobody','non','none','nonetheless','noone','no-one','nor','normally','not','nothing','notwithstanding','novel','now','nowhere','o','obviously','of','off','often','oh','ok','okay','old','on','once','one','ones','one\'s','only','onto','opposite','or','other','others','otherwise','ought','oughtn\'t','our','ours','ourselves','out','outside','over','overall','own','p','particular','particularly','past','per','perhaps','placed','please','plus','possible','presumably','probably','provided','provides','q','que','quite','qv','r','rather','rd','re','really','reasonably','recent','recently','regarding','regardless','regards','relatively','respectively','right','round','s','said','same','saw','say','saying','says','second','secondly','see','seeing','seem','seemed','seeming','seems','seen','self','selves','sensible','sent','serious','seriously','seven','several','shall','shan\'t','she','she\'d','she\'ll','she\'s','should','shouldn\'t','since','six','so','some','somebody','someday','somehow','someone','something','sometime','sometimes','somewhat','somewhere','soon','sorry','specified','specify','specifying','still','sub','such','sup','sure','t','take','taken','taking','tell','tends','th','than','thank','thanks','thanx','that','that\'ll','thats','that\'s','that\'ve','the','their','theirs','them','themselves','then','thence','there','thereafter','thereby','there\'d','therefore','therein','there\'ll','there\'re','theres','there\'s','thereupon','there\'ve','these','they','they\'d','they\'ll','they\'re','they\'ve','thing','things','think','third','thirty','this','thorough','thoroughly','those','though','three','through','throughout','thru','thus','till','to','together','too','took','toward','towards','tried','tries','truly','try','trying','t\'s','twice','two','u','un','under','underneath','undoing','unfortunately','unless','unlike','unlikely','until','unto','up','upon','upwards','us','use','used','useful','uses','using','usually','v','value','various','versus','very','via','viz','vs','w','want','wants','was','wasn\'t','way','we','we\'d','welcome','well','we\'ll','went','were','we\'re','weren\'t','we\'ve','what','whatever','what\'ll','what\'s','what\'ve','when','whence','whenever','where','whereafter','whereas','whereby','wherein','where\'s','whereupon','wherever','whether','which','whichever','while','whilst','whither','who','who\'d','whoever','whole','who\'ll','whom','whomever','who\'s','whose','why','will','willing','wish','with','within','without','wonder','won\'t','would','wouldn\'t','x','y','yes','yet','you','you\'d','you\'ll','your','you\'re','yours','yourself','yourselves','you\'ve','z','zero');
//we want to take the words that are not in the common words array and add a hash to them
$new_tweets = array();
$tweetWords = explode(' ', $tweet);

foreach ($tweetWords as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array(strtolower($value), array_map('strtolower', $commonWords)) == true)
     {
        $value = '#' . $value;
     }
     $new_tweets[] = $value;
  } 
$new_tweets = implode(' ', $new_tweets);
$tweet = (substr($new_tweets, 2));
$tweet = $tweet . '...' . 'http://www.***.com #bicycletouring'; 
print_r($tweet);
print_r(strlen($tweet));

$tweets    = eden('twitter')->tweets('***', '***', $_SESSION['access_token'], $_SESSION['access_secret']);
if (strlen($tweet) < 140){
    $tweets->tweet($tweet);
}
print '<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/></head><body>';
//print 'your tweet is' . '<br><br>' . $tweet;
print '<br><br>do you want to tweet it? if so click the button below.';
print '<form action="index.php" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="act" value="run">
<input type="submit" value="Run me now!">
</form>';
print '</body></html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to go through the motions of registering my twitter account and app with the Twitter module and then this worked in hook_cron.

```
  module_load_include('inc', 'twitter');
    $twitter_account = twitter_account_load('@accountname');
    drupal_set_message(t($twitter_account));
    $status = 'tnhis is the status';
    if (twitter_set_status($twitter_account, $status)) {
      drupal_set_message(t('Successfully posted to Twitter'));
    }
```